# Pick the value of different cell against particular cell

Tags: excel-formula

i have data in such manner for full month

```
Name    |   Date        |   Workdone 
--------+---------------+-------------
Mike    |   1/1/2015    |   aaaa
Tina    |   1/1/2015    |   sssss
Andrew  |   1/1/2015    |   eeee
Symond  |   1/1/2015    |   ffff
Mike    |   1/2/2015    |   gggg
Tina    |   1/2/2015    |   hhhh
Andrew  |   1/2/2015    |   nnn
Symond  |   1/2/2015    |   jjjj
```

Now i want a summery of each person for full moth in below manner

```
Mike    
------------+-------
1/1/2015    |   aaaa
1/2/2015    |   gggg

Symond  
------------+-------
1/1/2015    |   ffff
1/2/2015    |   jjjj
```

Kindly help me to prepare data in such manner by using formula

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a pivot table to achieve this summary.
Go to the insert tab in excel - select PivotTable on the far left - select data range.
Once the pivot table is inserted in the spreadsheet, on the far right of the screen you can select the attributes you want to view.